# How to login in Magento website using REST API

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

I am writing a REST API in Magento to login into the website with REST API. I have called the API to login the user through the web browser its logged In. After that, In the next tab on the browser when I typed my website it says "user is not logged In".

Please let me know how to keep the session when a user logged In through REST API.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have tab problem:**
You can create session inside your login api function to create session so when you go on next tab in browser Magento will first check session object and if it will find, it will directly logged in you.

**If you are using 3rd party tool such as iPhone, Android:**
You can pass token between the request and response. Here you have to cod a function based on token

This might help